# How do I clear biber's cache?

Tags: errors, biber

From time to time I have some trouble using biber as a backend for `biblatex`. I did some reading and found out that I have to clear the cache from time to time... I am a beginner at this. How can I do it?

Comment: Just delete the cache file ;-)

Comment: If you update your TeX distribution the latest `biber` has solved this problem, but in the meantime see the linked duplicate.